# Adding integers on appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, parseint

Please look at the following code. I can't get my values to add up. The digit just adds itself to the back of the string. Wonder any way to go about it.

```
$("a[name='older_post']").click(function(){
    $("div.main_ads_div a[name='older_post']").remove().fadeOut();
    var last_td_id=parseInt($("table.main_ads_table:last").find("td.load_ads:last").attr("id"),10);
    alert(last_td_id);   //OUTPUTS 38
    $("div.main_ads_div").append('<table class="main_ads_table" col="7" row="7"><tr><td class="load_ads" id="'+last_td_id+1+'"></td><td class="load_ads" id="'+last_td_id+2+'"></td><td class="load_ads" id="'+last_td_id+3+'"></td><td class="load_ads priority" id="'+last_td_id+4+'"></td><td class="load_ads priority" id="'+last_td_id+5+'"></td><td class="load_ads" id="'+last_td_id+6+'"></td><td class="load_ads" id="'+last_td_id+7+'"></td><td class="load_ads" id="'+last_td_id+8+'"></td></tr></table>');
});
```

So what I'm trying to get here is for the each `td` that appends, I'm trying to get `39, 40, 41, 42...` But I'm getting values such as `381, 382, 383,...` etc etc.

Any help here appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the addition in parentheses:

```
 ... + (last_td_id + 7) + ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are concating string with number, enclose the addition in parentheses to perform arithmatic operation on it.

Change

```
+last_td_id+1+
```

To

```
+(last_td_id+1)+
```

The [association](http://arguments.callee.info/2008/11/03/order-of-operations-in-javascript/) of `+` is left to right and in the statement `'....class="load_ads" id="'+last_td_id` first concatenates the left hand string with number (`last_td_id`) and gives a string which again concatenates the incremental number like (2 or 3 ..) to previous string. Putting the parenthesis around the number makes its `precedence` high and the calucation is performed first and result is concatenated in the string.

Comment: No need for parseInt - it would convert the number to string first

Comment: The parseInt is already included in the code: `var last_td_id=parseInt(`
@Bergi: _"it would convert the number to string first"_: Do you mean that the `parseint` returns a string? That line's kinda confusing, imo.

Comment: @Cerbrus: No, not "returns" but "expects". See step 1 of the [spec algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.2).

Comment: @Bergi: Ah, so the input parameters are first converted to strings, if they aren't yet... That makes more sense :P

Answer (score 1):

The `plus` operator only performs mathematical addition only if both operands are numbers. If one of them is a string, it will perform string concatenation (and cast the `1` to `"1"`).

Yet it is [left associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), and you are not using parenthesis. So your expression is evaluated as

```
(((…('<…' + id) + 1) + '"…') + id) + 2) + …
```

and every single step yields a string. You will need to enforce the addition to be executed first by wrapping it in parenthesis, as others have already mentioned:

```
'<…' + (id + 1) + '"…' + (id + 2) + …
// evaluated as
(((…('<…' + (id + 1)) + '"…') + (id + 2)) + …
```

Answer (score -1):

Using '+' in javascript always appends the variables/strings. Try something like this:

```
var c = (16 * 24) + 12;
d = c.toString();
```

Only then the var 'd' will give you the mathematical output

In your case, it could be

```
(last_td_id+4).toString();  and so on
```

Comment: `console.log((16 * 24) + 12)` and `console.log(((16 * 24) + 12).toString())` both return `396`. It's just that the latter returns it in string format. The calculations are exactly the same.
There is absolutely not point in using `.toString()` here.
And, no. `+` doesn't _always append_. When working with numbers, it adds. Just like it does in pretty much every other programming language out there.